# Click on a checkbox element using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

I am trying to automate loading and configuring a web page.
On this page I am trying to check the state of the checkbox and then click on a it if its unchecked.

**HTML** code for the page:

```
<fieldset id="wireless-24" class="left" style="display: block;">
                <div class="legend-edit text-orphan">
                    <legend>2.4 GHz network</legend><span>|</span><span id="edit-wireless-24"><a id="editWireless24Link" href="http://192.168.0.1/ui/1.0.99.162351/dynamic/home.html#">Edit</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row toggle-edit">
                    <label style="width: 126px;">Network:</label>
                    <label id="w-radio-enabled-text-24">Disabled</label> <!-- code sets the text to either Enabled or Disabled -->
                    <div class="cell" id="w-enabled-span-24">
                        <div class="check-item" style="">
                            <div><input type="checkbox" id="w-enabled-24" name="radio.band24.settings.isEnabled" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><span class="ui-checkbox"></span></div>
                            <div><label for="w-enabled-24" class="ui-checkbox">Enabled</label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

`Network` is the field I am trying to click on. I am using selenium and python.

I tried the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("w-radio-enabled-text-24").send_keys("Enabled")
browser.find_element_by_text("Network").click()
```

Comment: What happens when you`send_keys("Enabled")` to the radio button?

Comment: @Klot You didn't mention, Error details. Please do so.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are trying to `send_keys` to `label` tag, what is wrong. You can `send_keys` to `input` tag or equivalent. Secondly, you are trying to click on the `label`, what from my perspective also not effective. I believe you want something like this:

```
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id('w-enabled-24') # locate checkbox
if not checkbox.is_selected(): # check if checkbox is already selected
    checkbox.click() # if not, click on it
```

Also I would add `WebDriverWait`, to make sure, that element is visible and ready to be clicked like this:

```
checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "w-enabled-24")))
```

this will wait at least 10 seconds until checkbox will be clickable. The full code would be like this:

```
checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "w-enabled-24")))
if not checkbox.is_selected():
    checkbox.click()
```

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

More information about `WebDriverWait` you will find [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).